# Prolog - dyck path from origin to (2N,0)

Tags: prolog

Is called Dyck Path.
It is a plane of x and y axis,
where each step will be only (x+1,y+1) or (x+1,y-1) 
and will always stay above x-axis

K should means the peak of the Dyck path.
When K is 2 it should means that the peak is 2 and 3.

to form a legal sequence list of matching the parentheses a = '(', and b = ')' and has length 2N

Eg. [a,a,b,b] and [a,b,a,b] are the legal list for N = 2
    [a,b,b,a] and [b,a,b,a] do not satisfies for N = 2

need to define the predicate 
listFind(L,K,N) satisfies when L has list of order of 2N, for some k >= K

For example

```
|?- listFind(L,1,3).
L = [a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;
L = [a,b,a,a,b,b] ? ;
L = [a,a,b,b,a,b] ? ;
L = [a,a,b,a,b,b] ? ;
L = [a,a,a,b,b,b] ? ;
no


|?- listFind(L,2,3).
L = [a,a,b,b,a,b] ? ;
L = [a,a,b,a,b,b] ? ;
L = [a,a,a,b,b,b] ? ;
no
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you like to give some hint?

Answer (score 1):

the role of `K` is unclear to me. Anyway, here is a snippet satisying your test case:

```
listFind(L, K, N) :-
    N2 is N*2,
    length(L, N2),
    phrase(dyck, L),
    % satisfy condition on K
    run_length_encoded(L, RLE),
    [X-a|_] = RLE, X >= K.

% DCG for Dyck' language over alphabet `a,b`    
dyck --> [] ; [a], dyck, [b], dyck.

run_length_encoded([X|S], C) :-
    run_length_encoded(S, X, 1, C).

run_length_encoded([Y|S], X, N, E) :-
    (   X == Y
    ->  M is N + 1,
        run_length_encoded(S, X, M, E)
    ;   E = [N-X|T],
        run_length_encoded(S, Y, 1, T)
    ).
run_length_encoded([], X, C, [C-X]).
```

As you can see, the interpretation of K is

- the sequence *must* start with at least `K` consecutives `a`